# How to connect a Java Swing App with other instances of the app on the same network?

Tags: java

I have a Java Swing app that will be running concurrently on several computers on the same network. I'm trying to make it so that when one user makes an action on their running application, it affects all of the other applications that are running on the other systems. As in, when someone clicks an item from list_1 and then clicks an action button, actionOne for example (which launches a shortcut to another program), I want the item on list_1 to be grayed out (not enabled) for all other applications that are running.

I've tried messing around sockets/tcp/udp but couldn't seem to integrate it into the app correctly. What would be the most simple way to accomplish this?

```
public class Home extends JFrame{
    private JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try{
                    Home frame = new Home();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Home(){
        //I added some settings for the frame here
        //I added some settings for the JPanel that serves as my contentPane here
        setContentPane(contentPane)

        JList list_1 = new JList();
        //I added some settings for the list here
        contentPane.add(list_1);

        list_1.setModel(new AbstractListModel() {
            String[] values = new String[]{"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"};
            public int getSize(){ return values.length; }
            public Object getElement(int index){ return values[index]; }
        });
        list_1.setVisibleRowCount(4);

        class MyCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer{
            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

                JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
                //I added some settings for the cutom JList here
                if(isSelected){
                    label.setBackground(new Color(153, 204, 255));
                }
                return label;
            }
        }

        JButton btnLaunchAll = new JButton("Launch All");
        btnLaunchAll.addActionListener(new Action Listener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                try {
                    launchAll(list_1.getSelectedValue());
                } catch (Exception e1){
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        btnLaunchAll.setVisible(false);
        contentPane.add(btnLaunchAll);


        JButton btnActionOne = new JButton("Action 1");
        btnActionOne.addActionListener(new Action Listener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                try {
                    actionOne(list_1.getSelectedValue());
                } catch (IOException e1){
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        btnActionOne.setVisible(false);
        contentPane.add(btnActionOne);

        ListSelectionListener listSelection = new ListSelectionListener(){
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){
                String selectedItem = (String) list_1.getSelectedValue();
                btnLaunchAll.setVisible(true);
                btnActionOne.setVisible(true);
                .
                .
                .
            }

            public String selectedValue(){
                return (String) list_1.getSelectedValue();
            }
        };
        list_1.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
        list_1.addListSelectionListener(listSelection);
    }

    public void luanchAll(Object item) throws Exception {
        actionOne(item);
        Thread.sleep(4000);

        actionTwo(item);
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        .
        .
        .
    }

    public void actionOne(Object item) throws IOException {
        String itemName = (String) item;

        ProcessBuilder processOne = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "Path to Shortcut" + itemName + ".lnk");
        Process starting = processOne.start();
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

The code above is the generic version of what I have done so far. I'm not sure what the best way to add connectivity between multiple instances of the app is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [sockets](https://www.baeldung.com/a-guide-to-java-sockets) are the best way for doing this. You need a communication between all the instances of the app so you need one instance to comunicate with every other instance (which is not that easy).

Therefore the best way of doing this would probably be a [client-server-modell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model), where all the instances of the application are the clients and there is one server (which should not be one of the instances but a different type of programm).

In this model all the instances of the application need to **connect to the server and tell it when they started a process**, or done anything else that the other instances need to know. Then the server (who knows all instances because they all are connected to the master) can **tell all the instances that a specific resource is no longer availabe** (so they can disable the button).